# Cursor has disappeared

Tags: laptop

I have a Lenovo laptop my cursor has disappeared on my screen, and I don't know why! I can't make or change any activities that are needed for the program that it is stuck on. I've turned my computer off and on hoping the cursor comes back.

Comment: You may want to hook up an additional USB mouse. It may temporarily give you a mouse cursor back, which you can use to sort things out.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  What program is it stuck on?  Does the keyboard work?  Did you try an external mouse?

Answer (score 2):

If above does not work.
Try FN+F10 This also activates and deactivates the Track-Pad.
The cursor might be frozen some ware were you don't notice it because it is not moving.
When you use a Mouse it might be nice to turn of the Track-Pad so you don't move the Cursor by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Looking up a solution for this I found this on the Lenova site.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-P-Y-and-Z-series/Z500-Touch-Mouse-Pointer-Disappearing/td-p/1387161

> If it's just lately, can you try one of the following:
>
> 1. Disable "hide pointer while typing" under Control Panel (large icon view) > Mouse > Pointer Options Tab and enable "Show location of
>      pointer when I press CTRL key"
>
>    - [Link to picture](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/33521i9D3D753D0A918D1B/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1)
> 2. Uninstall the Touchpad Driver (ELAN or Synaptics) under Control Panel > Programs and reboot. Upon logging back in, Windows will use a
>      generic touchpad driver. Try to observe the mouse pointer behavior and
>      observe (you can always re-install the touchpad driver by navigating
>      to D:\Drivers\Touchpad or by downloading the driver from the Lenovo
>      website).
> 3. Boot in Safe Mode with Networking and observe the mouse pointer behavior. If all goes well, perform a clean boot and observe. If the
>      same problem, perform a System Restore in safe mode to undo any
>      possible updates that were installed on the system (ensure that you
>      make a backup copy of your files).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on my Yoga12 Laptop. First of all, the solution for people with a similar laptop:
Put the lid backwards to put the Yoga into tablet mode, wait for it to say "automatic rotation activated" or show in some other way that it's in tablet mode. Then open the lid back to normal laptop usage position and the pointer will appear again once you move a mouse/touchpad.

The reason why the pointer disappeared was that the trackpad somehow got deactivated (while doing a simple <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and logging back in, for me).

If you do not have such a laptop where you can switch to tablet mode, go to your mouse settings. It's called *Mouse Properties (Touchpad Clickpad Trackpad Trackpoint Mouse Pointer)* in the Win10 start menu). There, the rightmost tab - or maybe it's a different one for you - contains the option to activate/deactivate the trackpad. toggle it to activated.
[image: mouse settings]

If this does not help. Try plugging in a different Mouse. Does the pointer reappear? If yes, then your trackpad driver might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all the above options on my Lenovo Flex 5 laptop and was not able to figure out the issue. After several trial finally I got the solution. Apparently the Touchpad was off. You can easily fix this by searching Touchpad option on start menu. Click on "Turn off the Touchpad menu". A window will open that will show if the touchpad is 'On' or 'Off'.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the Ctrl + F6 keys at the same time and your cursor pops back up. A quick fix for me.

Comment: Do you know or can you explain why this resolves the issue? CTRL+F6 has no default function but could be assigned to specific functions inside different applications: https://defkey.com/what-means/ctrl-f6

Comment: Thank that worked for me to.

Answer (score 0):

I went to settings, mouse, scrolled down to additional options, clicked on the pointer options tab, and unchecked hide while typing. Also, I made the mouse green.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).